# Polars dataframe columns selection

Tags: python-polars

In pandas we can take columns from database using , df_new = df[["A","B"]]. How to do similar thing using polars ?

I tried df_new = df.get_columns(["A","B"]). But it is giving error

Comment: It would be better if you can also share the error.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to read or skim through Polars introduction in here:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/introduction.html. It is nicely written with some good examples.

You can choose columns by using Polars select statement

```
df_new = df.select(pl.col(["A","B"]))
```

or

```
df_new = df.select([pl.col("A"), pl.col("B")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from ***Polars 0.18.1*** You can use [`polars.selectors.by_name` to select all columns matching the given names](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.by_name).

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import polars.selectors as cs
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "id": [1, 2, 3],
...         "name": ["John", "Jane", "Jake"],
...         "else": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> print(df.select(cs.by_name('id', 'name')))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ name │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ John │
│ 2   ┆ Jane │
│ 3   ┆ Jake │
└─────┴──────┘
```